# ¿Cómo acortar la paginación en PHP?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Tengo una paginación en PHP, la cual es como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Paginacion]

Sin embargo, va aumentando el número de páginas conforme voy ingresando más registros a la base de datos, ya que me los despliega por página 10 registros.
Me gustaría que por ejemplo, en mi paginación se mostrara del 1 al 10, y que cuando llegue al 10, se muestre del 10 al 20... No se si me explico.

Dejo el código de PHP que utilice.

```
 <nav aria-label="Page navigation" class="text-center">
     <ul class="pagination">
        <?php
        if ($total_paginas > 1) {
           if ($pagina != 1)
              echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.($pagina-1).'" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>';
              for ($i = 1; $i <=$total_paginas; $i++){
                  if ($pagina == $i)
                      echo '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$pagina.'</a></li>';
                  else
                      echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
              }
              if ($pagina != $total_paginas) {
                 echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.($pagina+1).'"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>';
              }
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aquí te dejo una opción basada en tu código y con mínimos cambios sobre el mismo.

La idea es bastante sencilla (aunque no sé si la explicaré bien) y consiste en lo siguiente: mostrar siempre un máximo de 10 enlaces que empezarán con la unidad y terminarán con dicha unidad+9 (o el total de páginas si unidad+9 es mayor). Eso quiere decir que para la página 5, los enlaces mostrados serán del 1 al 10; para la página 13, los enlaces serán del 11 al 20, etc.

Para ello hace falta: calcular cuál será el primer número y el último número a mostrar, y hacer que el bucle sea sólo entre ellos. Luego a la hora de mostrar las flechas habrá que comprobar si la primera página es menor que 10 (en cuyo caso no se mostrará la flecha a la izquierda) o si la última página es igual al total de páginas (en cuyo caso no se mostrará la flecha a la derecha).

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo se haría:

> Nota- Estoy (casi) convencido de que se puede simplificar de alguna manera el cálculo del primero y el último, pero mi cerebro está frito ahora mismo (inicialmente tenía un cálculo super-complicado y lo he ido reduciendo hasta esto)

```
<?php
// calculamos la primera y última página a mostrar
$primera = $pagina - ($pagina % 10) + 1;
if ($primera > $pagina) { $primera = $primera - 10; }
$ultima = $primera + 9 > $total_paginas ? $total_paginas : $primera + 9; 
?>
<nav aria-label="Page navigation" class="text-center">
     <ul class="pagination">
        <?php
        if ($total_paginas > 1) {
            // comprobamos $primera en lugar de $pagina
            if ($primera != 1)
                echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.($primera-1).'" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>';

            // mostramos de la primera a la última
            for ($i = $primera; $i <=$ultima; $i++){
                if ($pagina == $i)
                    echo '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$pagina.'</a></li>';
                else
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }

            if ($i <= $total_paginas)
                echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.($i).'"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>';
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: ¡Eres un brujo! (En el buen sentido). ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Haciendo algo similar a lo que hizo Alvaro, tomando tu código como base, esta es una versión levemente distinta, los objetivos son:

- Mostrar las 5 páginas anteriores y las 5 siguientes a la actual
- Mostrar la primera página si no está en el grupo anterior
- Mostrar la última página si no está en el grupo del primer punto

La idea de esta respuesta es agregar una opción para quienes encuentren esta pregunta "en el futuro".

```
$primera = ($pagina - 5) > 1 ? $pagina - 5 : 1;
$ultima = ($pagina + 5) < $total_paginas ? $pagina + 5 : $total_paginas;

if ($total_paginas > 1) {

    // flecha anterior
    if ($pagina != 1) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.($pagina-1).'" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span></a></li>';
    }

    // si la primera del grupo no es la pagina 1, mostramos la 1 y los ...
    if ($primera != 1) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina=1">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        echo '<li>...</li>';
    }

    // mostramos la página actual, las 5 anteriores y las 5 posteriores
    for ($i = $primera; $i <= $ultima; $i++){
        if ($pagina == $i)
            echo '<li class="active"><a href="#">'.$pagina.'</a></li>';
        else
            echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }

    // si la ultima del grupo no es la ultima (lol), mostramos la ultima y los ...
    if ($ultima != $total_paginas) {
        echo '<li>...</li>';
        echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.$total_paginas.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }

    // flecha siguiente
    if ($pagina != $total_paginas) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'?pagina='.($pagina+1).'"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span></a></li>';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Igual es cambiar un poco el concepto de lo que usas ahora. Yo lo hago de manera que la paginación, la realizo en una clase y luego en el `PHP`, llamo a la paginación.

Este archivo lo tengo para una conexión `PDO`, pero si buscas por Internet, seguro que lo encuentras para `mysql` o `mysqli`

> **paginacion.php**
>
> ```
> class PDO_Pagination
> {
>   public $connection;
>       public $total;
>       public $page;
>       public $total_page;
>       public $start_row;
>       public $item;
>       public $max_pages;
>       public $max_rows;
>       public $step;
>       public $max;
>       public $param;
>       public $btn_first_page;
>       public $btn_last_page;
>       public $btn_next_page;
>       public $btn_back_page;
>       public $btn_page;
>       public $btn_active;
>
>       public function __construct($connection) {
>       $this->btn_first_page = 'Previous';
>       $this->btn_last_page = 'Last';
>       $this->btn_next_page = 'Next';
>       $this->btn_back_page = 'Back';
>       $this->btn_page = 'Pag.';
>       $this->btn_active = 'active';
>       return $this->connection = $connection;
>   }
>
>   public function rowCount($query){
>       $query = $this->connection->prepare($query);
>       $query->execute();
>       $this->total = $query->rowCount();
>   }
>
>       public function config($max_pages, $max_rows){
>       $this->start_row = 0;
>       $this->item = 0;
>       $this->max_pages = $max_pages;
>       $this->max_rows = $max_rows;
>       $this->total_page = $this->total / $this->max_rows;
>
>       if (isset($_GET["page"])){
>           $this->page = $_GET["page"];
>           if ($this->page < 0 || !preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $this->page)){
>               return;
>           }
>
>           $this->start_row = $this->page * $this->max_rows;
>
>           $this->item = $_GET["item"];
>           if ($this->item < 0  || !preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $this->item)){
>               return;
>           }
>
>           $this->max_pages = $this->max_pages + $this->max_rows;
>
>           $this->max = $_GET["max"];
>           if ($this->max < 0  || !preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $this->max)){
>               return;
>           }
>           $this->max_pages = $this->max;
>       }
>
>
>       if(isset($_GET["next_page"])){
>           $this->page = $_GET["next_page"];
>           if ($this->page < 0  || !preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $this->page)){
>               return;
>           }
>
>           $this->start_row = $this->page * $this->max_rows;
>
>           $this->item = $_GET["item"];
>           if ($this->item < 0  || !preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $this->item)){
>               return;
>           }
>
>           $this->max = $_GET["max"];
>           if ($this->max < 0  || !preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $this->max)){
>               return;
>           }
>               $this->max_pages = $this->max + 1;
>           }
>
>           if(isset($_GET["back_page"])){
>           $this->page = $_GET["back_page"] - 1;
>           if ($this->page < 0  || !preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $this->page)){
>               return;
>           }
>           $this->start_row = $this->page * $this->max_rows;
>
>           $this->item = $_GET["item"] - 1;
>           if ($this->item < 0  || !preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $this->item)){
>               return;
>           }
>
>           $this->max = $_GET["max"];
>               if ($this->max < 0  || !preg_match("/^([0-9])+$/", $this->max)){
>               return;
>           }
>
>           $this->max_pages = $this->max - 1;
>       }
>
>           if (isset($_GET["previous"])){
>           $this->max_pages = $this->max_pages;
>           $this->start_row=0;
>           $this->item = 0;
>       }
>   }
>
>   public function pages($class=''){
>
>   if($this->item >= 1){
>           echo "<a class='$class'  href='?previous=1".$this->param."'>$this->btn_first_page</a>";
>           echo "<a class='$class'  href='?back_page=$this->page&item=$this->item&max=$this->max_pages".$this->param."'>$this->btn_back_page</a>";
>       }
>       for($x = $this->item; $x < $this->max_pages; $x++){
>       while($x * $this->max_rows < $this->total){
>           $p = $x+1;
>           $this->page == $p-1 ? $active = ' ' . $this->btn_active : $active = null;
>           echo "<a class='$class$active' href='?page=$x&item=$this->item&max=$this->max_pages".$this->param."'>$p</a>";
>           break;
>       }
>   }
>
>       $numbers = $this->page+1;
>       echo "<span class='$class'>$this->btn_page <b>$numbers</b></span>";
>
>       if ($this->max_pages * $this->max_rows < $this->total){
>       $this->page = $this->page+1;
>       $this->item = $this->item + 1;
>       echo "<a class='$class' href='?next_page=$this->page&item=$this->item&max=$this->max_pages".$this->param."'>$this->btn_next_page</a>";
>
>       $this->page = round($this->total_page - 1);
>       $this->item = round($this->total_page - $this->max_pages);
>       $this->max = round($this->total_page);
>       echo "<a class='$class'  href='?page=$this->page&item=$this->item&max=$this->max".$this->param."'>$this->btn_last_page</a>";
>   }
>   }
> }
> ```

La llamada en el código sería:

```
<?php
$connection = dbConnect ();
$pagination = new PDO_Pagination($connection);
$pagination->rowCount("SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE publicado=1");
$pagination->config(5, 30); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE publicado=1 ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT $pagination->start_row,
$pagination->max_rows";
$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$model = array();
while($rows = $query->fetch())
 {
  $model[] = $rows;
}
 foreach($model as $row){
  echo "<li class='li_noticias'>";
  echo "<a href='".$row['idref'].".html' rel='follow'>";
  //echo "<a href='noticias2.php?ref=".$row['idref']."' rel='follow'>";
   echo $row['titulo'];
   echo "</a>";
   echo "</li>";
 }
?>
```