# Limitar paginación PHP

Tags: php, html, paginacion

Tengo una paginación PHP con HTML, que funciona bien, hace lo que realmente quiero, pero acabe de encontrar un problema que cuando tengo muchos registros, la paginación se crece mucho y queda mal y feo, la idea seria hacer un resumen en la paginación, ya sea que muestre de a 10 en 10 o de alguna forma que no se vea tan mal.

Así esta actualmente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la paginación es el siguiente:

```
$productos_x_pagina = 8;
    $paginas = $total_articulos_bd/$productos_x_pagina;
    $paginas = ceil($paginas);



<div class="col-sm-12" id="Paginacion">
                  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                  <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']<=1? 'disabled' : '' ?>"><a class="page-link" href="Catalogo_Productos.php?pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']-1 ?>">Anterior</a></li>

                    <?php for($i=0; $i<$paginas; $i++){ ?>
                    <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']==$i+1 ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a class="page-link" href="Catalogo_Productos.php?pagina=<?php echo $i+1; ?>"><?php echo $i+1; ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['pagina']>=$paginas ? 'disabled' : '' ?>"><a class="page-link" href="Catalogo_Productos.php?pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']+1 ?>">Siguiente</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo, una es buscar dentro del mismo link que sugiere S.O.es -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20438/c%c3%b3mo-acortar-la-paginaci%c3%b3n-en-php?rq=1

Comment: Otra diferente es limitar la cantidad de numeros con el uso de un plugin como se suguiere aca -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420470/limit-the-number-of-pages-displayed-in-bootstrap-3-pagination/38764638

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo acortar la paginación en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20438/c%c3%b3mo-acortar-la-paginaci%c3%b3n-en-php)

Comment: Gracias, pude adaptar una de esas