# agregar paginación - php

Tags: php

buen día, estoy cargando todas las imágenes desde base de datos sin problemas pero quiero agregarle paginación para que se vea mas ordenado y no cargue en toda la pantalla las imágenes y la navegación sea muy complicada.

mi.php

```js
<?php
$servename = "localhost";
$database = "imagenes";
$username = "imagenes";
$password = "KenKen=123";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servename, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_query($conn,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

if(!$conn){
    die("Conection failed" . mysqli_connect_eror());
}

$sql = "select * from imagenenes ORDER by ID ASC";

?>


 <?php
                                     
                                 $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3) or die("database error: " .mysqli_error($conn));
                                  while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
                             ?>   
                             
                             
<div class="col-md-3">
<a>
<div class="collection-item" style="margin-bottom: -5px; width:250px" >
<div class="collection-img">
<img src="<?php  echo 'apiMuseo/fotos_publicaciones_galeria/Imagenes/'.$record['imagen'] ?>" alt="" >
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>

                              <?php
                                     }
                                      
                                ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes usar LIMIT en tu consulta SQL para obtener solo la cantidad de elementos deseados por página, una vez que lo tengas debes calcular la paginación en función del total de elementos en la base de datos.

Te agrege una sección de paginación al final del código para que puedas controlarla.

Aqui el codigo:

```php
<?php
$servename = "localhost";
$database = "imagenes";
$username = "imagenes";
$password = "KenKen=123";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servename, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed" . mysqli_connect_eror());
}

// Aqui es donde ajustas los registros
$elementosPorPagina = 10; 
$paginaActual = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($paginaActual - 1) * $elementosPorPagina;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenenes ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $inicio, $elementosPorPagina";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Database error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
?>

<!-- en esta seccion muestra el resultado -->
<?php while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a>
            <div class="collection-item" style="margin-bottom: -5px; width:250px">
                <div class="collection-img">
                    <img src="<?php echo 'apiMuseo/fotos_publicaciones_galeria/Imagenes/' . $record['imagen'] ?>" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<!-- y esta seria la seccion de paginación -->
<div class="pagination">
    <?php
    $sqlTotal = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM imagenenes";
    $resultTotal = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTotal);
    $filaTotal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTotal);
    $totalElementos = $filaTotal['total'];
    $totalPaginas = ceil($totalElementos / $elementosPorPagina);

    if ($paginaActual > 1) {
        echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual - 1) . "'>&laquo; Anterior</a> ";
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPaginas; $i++) {
        $claseActiva = ($i == $paginaActual) ? 'active' : '';
        echo "<a class='$claseActiva' href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a> ";
    }
    
    if ($paginaActual < $totalPaginas) {
        echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual + 1) . "'>Siguiente &raquo;</a> ";
    }
</div>

<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Este seria el CSS basico de la paginacion por si no lo tienes

```css
.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.pagination a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
}

.pagination a.active {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.pagination a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

#### Recomendacion:

Debes indentar mejor tu codigo para que puedas vizualizar mejor los bloques.

#### Resultado del Codigo:

#### Lo ajuste para que aparecieran de 3 en 3 tengo un total de 10 imagenes por eso la paginacion en el ejemplo dice 4 paginas (en el codigo donde dice 10 puse 3)

[image: Comienza en la uno]
[image: Seleccione la tercera]
[image: luego la ultima]

Comment: buen dia, esta apareciendo la paginación pero no esta cargando las imágenes en el <?php while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) { 
                             ?>

Comment: Revisa tu SELECT que pusiste como ejemplo, sobre todo el FROM "imagenenes" no se si lo tienes bien ve si es correcto el SQL, yo hice un ejemplo y funciona, por otro lado revisa las rutas. yo no cambie nada de tu consulta original solo agregue el limite al sql para llevar el control, por favor revisa.

Comment: listo funciono, una pregunta como hago para que aparezca las flechas de ir a tras o adelante y saber en que pagina estoy parado ?

Comment: detecte un inconveniente cuando voy a cambiar de una pagina a otra en la paginación se actualiza toda la pagina web, no hay forma  que solo se actualice la paginación y no todo la pagina.php ?

Comment: ACTUALIZACIÓN: Ya te modifique el código para que te aparezcan las flechas con anterior o siguiente junto con unas flechas.

Comment: Para que no se actualice la pagina debes cambiar TU código original y trabajarlo con Javascript, creas una funcion fecth que llama a tu php y lo haces de forma dinamica.

Comment: listo voy a revisar, ultima  pregunta referente a la paginación por ejemplo tengo 50 paginas en la paginación y se muy engorroso ya que ocuparía mucho espacio como se podría dejar para que no se muestre todas las 50 paginas  si no algo mas resumido para que se pueda ir navegando en la paginación, como seria ?

Comment: Con este código el camino más fácil es aumentar el valor de paginación en ``` $elementosPorPagina = 10;``` y el otro camino sería agregar otra lógica de programación que te limite el FOR a solo 10 bloques o 20 bloques y crear a los lados de "anterior" y "siguiente" dos botones más que hagan ese salto.

Comment: Por favor recuerda colocar el check que la respuesta es CORRECTA si realmente soluciono tu pregunta inicial, siempre a la orden.

Comment: listo, me podrías colaborar con el código "otra lógica de programación que te limite el FOR a solo 10 bloques o 20 bloques y crear a los lados de "anterior" y "siguiente" dos botones más que hagan ese salto" se lo agradecería

Comment: Ya existe respuesta a eso, para no duplicar te invito a que pases por https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20438/c%C3%B3mo-acortar-la-paginaci%C3%B3n-en-php

Comment: no he podido implementar a mi código , si me puedes colaborar se lo agradecería