# paginación extensa php

Tags: javascript, php

buen día, tengo una paginación de imágenes con php y funciona sin problemas pero tengo el siguiente inconveniente cuando estoy en la paginación y voy a de una pagina a otra me carga sin problemas pero también se actualiza todo mi sitio.php como hago para que cuando me desplace de una pagina a otra en mi paginación no se actualice todo mi.php

mi.php

```js
<?php
$servename = "localhost";
$database = "*********";
$username = "*********";
$password = "*********";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servename, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed" . mysqli_connect_eror());
}

// Aqui es donde ajustas los registros
$elementosPorPagina = 10; 
$paginaActual = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($paginaActual - 1) * $elementosPorPagina;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenenes ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $inicio, $elementosPorPagina";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Database error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
?>

<!-- en esta seccion muestra el resultado -->
<?php while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a>
            <div class="collection-item" style="margin-bottom: -5px; width:250px">
                <div class="collection-img">
                    <img src="<?php echo 'apiMuseo/fotos_publicaciones_galeria/Imagenes/' . $record['imagen'] ?>" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<!-- y esta seria la seccion de paginación -->
<div class="pagination">
    <?php
    $sqlTotal = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM imagenenes";
    $resultTotal = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTotal);
    $filaTotal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTotal);
    $totalElementos = $filaTotal['total'];
    $totalPaginas = ceil($totalElementos / $elementosPorPagina);

    if ($paginaActual > 1) {
        echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual - 1) . "'>&laquo; Anterior</a> ";
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPaginas; $i++) {
        $claseActiva = ($i == $paginaActual) ? 'active' : '';
        echo "<a class='$claseActiva' href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a> ";
    }
    
    if ($paginaActual < $totalPaginas) {
        echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual + 1) . "'>Siguiente &raquo;</a> ";
    }
</div>

<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Una cosa, no es buena práctica publicar el password de tu base de datos en internet. En este caso es de tu localhost pero para que lo tengas en cuenta, por si acaso.

Comment: listo muchas gracias por la recomendación, igual los accesos que coloco son otros

Comment: te refieres a cómo hacer para que no ocurra una recarga de página?

Comment: por ejemplo la paginación me carga dos paginas pagina uno y pagina dos pero si me voy a desplazar en la paginación en la pagina dos al darle clic esta me carga pero también se recarga todo el mi.php, lo que necesito es que al darle clic a la pagina de la paginación solo me cargue los datos sin actualizarse toda mi pagina.php

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, si lo que quieres es que solamente cambie la información en la parte de la página que pertenece a la paginación y no el resto de la página, entonces debes usar una llamada AJAX. Usando solo PHP siempre se producirá una recarga de la página completa porque actúa del lado del servidor.

Comment: pero como seria implementado en el código que ya tengo ?

Comment: Creas un archivo independiente que maneje la paginación y que reciba como parámetro el número de página (al hacer click en el botón). Lo llamas usando AJAX y los resultados que obtengas los cargas en un <div> dentro de tu página. De esa manera solo cambia el contenido del <div> al cual pertenece la paginación.

Comment: me puedes colaborar como seria con mi código, he intentado y no he podido hacerlo, se lo agradecería

Comment: [Google es tu amigo.](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+pagination+using+ajax) Nadie te ayudará sin que lo intentes primero.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [agregar paginación - php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/605864/agregar-paginaci%c3%b3n-php)