# cargar base de datos de mi paginación con ajax - php

Tags: javascript, php

buen día, estoy cargando mis imágenes desde base de datos en una paginación pero requiero que me carguen desde ajax por que asi como lo tengo cada vez que me muevo en la paginación se me actualiza todo mi.php y solo necesito que vaya cargando únicamente la paginación a medida que me vaya moviendo dentro de la paginación.

```js
<?php
$servename = "localhost";
$database = "*********";
$username = "*********";
$password = "*********";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servename, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed" . mysqli_connect_eror());
}

// Aqui es donde ajustas los registros
$elementosPorPagina = 10; 
$paginaActual = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($paginaActual - 1) * $elementosPorPagina;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM imagenenes ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $inicio, $elementosPorPagina";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Database error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
?>

<!-- en esta seccion muestra el resultado -->
<?php while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a>
            <div class="collection-item" style="margin-bottom: -5px; width:250px">
                <div class="collection-img">
                    <img src="<?php echo 'apiMuseo/fotos_publicaciones_galeria/Imagenes/' . $record['imagen'] ?>" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<!-- y esta seria la seccion de paginación -->
<div class="pagination">
    <?php
    $sqlTotal = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM imagenenes";
    $resultTotal = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlTotal);
    $filaTotal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTotal);
    $totalElementos = $filaTotal['total'];
    $totalPaginas = ceil($totalElementos / $elementosPorPagina);

    if ($paginaActual > 1) {
        echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual - 1) . "'>&laquo; Anterior</a> ";
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPaginas; $i++) {
        $claseActiva = ($i == $paginaActual) ? 'active' : '';
        echo "<a class='$claseActiva' href='?pagina=$i'>$i</a> ";
    }
    
    if ($paginaActual < $totalPaginas) {
        echo "<a href='?pagina=" . ($paginaActual + 1) . "'>Siguiente &raquo;</a> ";
    }
</div>

<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Giovanny... Cuál es tu pregunta? "Cómo hacerlo?" Qué has investigado acerca de paginación? Qué has intentado? Cuál es el problema que te detiene? Cómo has intentado resolverlo? Qué resultados obtuviste? Cuál era el resultado esperado?}

Comment: hola buen dia, es que tengo un inconveniente con el código actual , cuando me carga la paginación y me aparece pagina 1 , 2 etc al darle clic alguna pagina por ejmplo al 2 me carga los registros pero tambien vuelve a cargar todo el php, como hago para que solo me cargue la pagina que le doy clic y no se recargue todo el php

Comment: esta claro que el codigo actual no sirve ... entonces la pregunta es que has intentado aparte de lo que ya te percatas que no sirve?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [agregar paginación - php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/605864/agregar-paginaci%c3%b3n-php)